# .htaccess file for utc parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am using htaccess to make all my pages look like this

```
site.com/category/artikel/
```

using this code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ page.php?category=$1&articel=$2 [L]
```

Now I want to receive utc parameters, like this ( the website that send me the utc parameters are sending "?" before the utc parameters)

```
site.com/category/artikel/?utm_source=MM&utm_parameter=12345
```

Now I can access this data and store them in the cookies only if the link was with & instead of?

my question is:

is it possible to change it on Htaccess 
I mean when any think start with (?) to be changes (&) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this in your rule add QSA flag,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ page.php?category=$1&articel=$2 [QSA,L]
```

**[QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)**

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

Comment: The issue that I have several pages like this and I have multi levels as well like : site.com/category/tags/today/test , 

I was looking for somthing like this 


RewriteRule ^(.*)\?utm_source(.*)$ &utm_source$  [L]

Comment: The `QSA` flag will work with every of your rewriterule regardless, try it and if you have some other condition altogether mention it in your question.